# Are HTTP GET variables indexable by Google

Tags: http, seo, get, http-get

Are HTTP GET variables indexable by Google?

e.g. if I link to http://myhomepage.com/show?id=14&awesome-calvin-and-hobbes-stuffed-zombies-i-made

will the part after the & be picked up by Google's search engine as having to do with Calvin and Hobbes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can see it from search results (e.g. search for "search q" - many of the results include HTTP GET variables). Some CMS systems e.g. Drupal use such URLs by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google does index URLs with query strings and they do parse them for keywords. It doesn't mean you'll rank well for them, though.